# Using range operator with if statements in perl

Tags: perl

I want to achieve something like this the more real one.

```
##
Start
abc
def 123 45 156.356
ghi
jkl  345 33  478.89
end

Start
abc
eef  123 45 456.356
ghi
jkl  345 33  678.89
end

Start
abc
eef  123 45 256.356
ghi
kkl  345 33  878.89
end
```

I would like to go through each set between

```
if(/Start/../end/)

if($line =~ def) $$ ($line =~jkl\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)) { if($3 <$VALUE) {  { print "whole set"}
```

Ans:
Start
abc
def 123 45 156.356
ghi
jkl  345 33  478.89
end

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to print only                                                                     Start
abc
def
ghi
jkl
end

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use the range operator for this, but instead read in paragraph mode. You can do this by setting `$/` to an empty string:

```
local $/ = '';
while ( <> ) {
    print if m/def/ and m/jkl/;
}
```

In doing so, you split your data on empty lines (special use of `$/`) so each iteration of the while loop has the whole lot from `Start` to `end`. And then you can test a regex against that chunk.

`<>` is a magic operator that reads data on STDIN or filenames specified on command line via `@ARGV`.

Edit: From comments:

> The prob is more After I match m/def/ I need to capture the value like $3 from that line "def 0 123 456.567. Then I need to compare it with a value ( $3< $value) if true print the whole set. repeat for def & jkl Start abc def 0 123 456.567 ghi jkl end

So this you can do two ways - pattern matching a line within the block and extracting a value is pretty easy:

```
local $/ = '';
while ( <DATA> ) {
    my @def_values = m/def (\d+) (\d+) (\d+)/;
    print if m/def/ and m/jkl/ and @def_values[2] > 2;
}


__DATA__
##
Start
abc
def 0 123 456.567
ghi
jkl
end

Start
abc
eef
ghi
jkl
end

Start
abc
eef
ghi
kkl
end
```

For example.

Or perhaps:

```
local $/ = '';
while ( <DATA> ) {
    my %stuff = m/(\w+) (.*)/;
    $stuff{$_} = [split(' ', $stuff{$_})] for keys %stuff;        
    print if m/def/ and m/jkl/ and $stuff{'def'}[2] >2 ;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use $/  but was not aware of "" empty string. The prob is more After I match m/def/ I need to capture the value like $3 from that line "def 0 123 456.567. Then I need to compare it with a value ( $3< $value)  if true print the whole set.  repeat for def & jkl                                                                    Start
abc
def  0 123 456.567
ghi
jkl
end

Comment: OK. Can you edit that into your question.  It is pretty easy to extract from the current chunk.

Answer (score 1):

If you're processing input line by line, then you want to save them and print later if conditions are met,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines;
my ($one, $two);
my $VALUE = 1000;

while (<DATA>) {

  if (my $ff = /Start/ .. /end/) { 
    push @lines, $_;
    $one ||= /def/;
    $two ||= /jkl\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/ && $3 <$VALUE;

    # end of flip-flop block reached?
    if ($ff =~ /E0/) {
      print @lines if $one and $two;
      @lines = ();
      $one = $two = undef;
    }
  }
}

__DATA__
Start
abc
def 123 45 156.356
ghi
jkl  345 33  478.89
end

Start
abc
eef  123 45 456.356
ghi
jkl  345 33  678.89
end

Start
abc
eef  123 45 256.356
ghi
kkl  345 33  878.89
end
```

Comment: $one ||= /def/; Could you please explain this "||=" ? I saw somewhere but I don't know how to use without know meaning.

Comment: That's `or equals' - if the first value is _false_ (undef/zero/empty string) it instead assigns the second value.

Comment: @Sobrique: Superb... I got it.

Comment: Equally superb way using range operator some new operators :)